# Where do registers AL and AX overflow to?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, integer-overflow, ctf

Please tell me what will be the result of the following assembly (pseudo)code?
We have set all bits of the register `EAX` to 0, so in turn we also have `AH`, `AL`, and `AX` as 0. But when I subtract the lowest bit of `AL`, we will take the two's complement and add, giving us a bunch of 1s followed by a 0.

```
XOR eax, eax
SUB al 0x01
```

So in summary, my question is that on executing the code above, will **just `AL`** be full of 1s, or will it also **carry over to `AX` and `EAX`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Carry-out from add/sub goes into CF, the carry flag in EFLAGS.**

The operand of `sub al, 1` is AL, not EAX.  **The high 24 bits of EAX can't be affected by an instruction with 8-bit operand size.**

If you wanted to flip the whole EAX to all-ones, you'd need to use `sub eax, 1`. (or `not eax`, or `dec eax`).  `sub al, 1` is a different instruction, and the difference is that it only affects AL (and EFLAGS), not any bits outside AL.

---

> giving us a bunch of 1s followed by a 0.

No.  In 2's complement, `-1` is represented by a number with all its bits set.  For example, in 8-bit it's `0xFF`, in 32-bit it's `0xFFFFFFFF`.   With a `0` bit at the bottom, it would represent `-2`.

> will just AL be full of 1s, or will it also carry over to AX and EAX.

Just AL.  You could have just tried it yourself (and then asked for an explanation of the result if you were still puzzled).

Comment: Thanks, and I am really bad at Assembly, so I am trying reversing in CTF, I did not manage to compile and check.